# nested For loop error in VBA cant get past

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a macro that will look at all sentences in a cell, compare to all sentences in the cell to the left.  Then if the sentence does not exits, change font to red, else move on to next sentence.  However I am running into an issue with the for loops.  I am relatively new to VBA but got a coding background so any help would be appreciated.  Please see below and ignore the commented out sections as I have not finished/done those parts yet.  The error that I am getting is a next with no for error.  I have two in the code that have ** next to it which is where the debug tells me the problem is.

```
Sub CompareSentence()

Dim n As Long, m As Long, k As Long
Dim c1sentence As String, c2sentence As String, u As String, split2sentence() As String, temp As String
Dim cell1column As Integer, cell2column As Integer, counter1 As Integer, periodcounter As Integer, totalperiods As Integer, totalperiodsc2 As Integer, j As Integer
Dim split1sentence() As String
Dim bool As Boolean


counter1 = 0
k = 0
cell1column = 9
cell2column = 8
i = 4
'start loop for i = 1 to END OF USED ROWS      'Loop through all rows
                                                'need loop to go left and right to search for sentence in adjacent cell
                                                '(go from right to left, search, not found = change, found = next sentence to search)
                                    

    c1sentence = Trim(Cells(i, cell1column).Value)
    c2sentence = Trim(Cells(i, cell2column).Value)
    
    split1sentence = Split(c1sentence, ".")
    split2sentence = Split(c2sentence, ".")
    
    If c1sentence = c2sentence Then
        MsgBox ("Match")
        'go down one row
    
    Else

        totalperiods = UBound(split1sentence) - LBound(split1sentence) + 1
        totalperiodsc2 = UBound(split2sentence) - LBound(split2sentence) + 1
        periodcounter = 0
        For j = 0 To totalperiods
        For periodcounter = 0 To totalperiodsc2
            If split1sentence(j) = split2sentence(periodcounter) Then
                    periodcounter = totalperiodsc2
                                                        'exit this loop to look at next sentence
                
            Else
                If periodcounter = totalperiodsc2 Then
                    'change font of split1sentence(j) to red
                        
                    
            End If
        Next periodcounter*********************
        Next j***************************
        
    End If
    
'Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I count 3 `If`s but only 2 `End If`. Note that `Else`...`If` is not equivalent to `ElseIf`. Looks like you need an `End If` to close `If periodcounter = totalperiodsc2 Then`.